# How do I 'run as' 'Network Service'?

Tags: command-line, permissions, runas, network-service

I am trying to run a process as another account. I have the command:

```
runas "/user:WIN-CLR8YU96CL5\network service" "abwsx1.exe"
```

but then this asks for the password. However there is no password set for the network service.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 158):

Use [PsExec.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) from SysInternals, running from an elevated command prompt.

e.g. this will open a new command prompt running as NETWORK SERVICE:

```
psexec -i -u "nt authority\network service" cmd.exe
```

this will run it as LOCAL SYSTEM:

```
psexec -i -s cmd.exe
```

You can verify these by running `whoami` from the cmd prompt.

See also:

- http://forum.sysinternals.com/how-to-start-cmdexe-as-network-service_topic15797.html
- [Interactive command prompt as NETWORK SERVICE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151184/interactive-command-prompt-as-network-service)

Comment: @stej - Not for me. Try running it from an elevated command prompt, i.e. run your command prompt as Administrator.

Comment: No idea, psexec  version is 2.11. I also tried it on winserver 2012 running as Azure cloud service from elevated console, but it still asks for password.

Comment: Asks for password for me too.

Comment: Works fine on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2. EDIT: PSExec 1.98 EDIT 2: Also 2.11

Comment: This appears not to work on 64-bit machines.  A workaround is to use [devxexec](http://serverfault.com/a/317978/64996) instead, which does work.

Comment: Works fine for me on 64-bit machines.

Comment: @Rory: I think I figured it out.  For Network Service (at least in an Azure Role), it appears you have to specify the full exact path to cmd.exe.  For some reason it doesn't have a default PATH variable or something...

Comment: On Windows10, this works only if run from elevated command prompt. Otherwise, 'Couldn't install PSEXESVC service:Access is denied'.

Answer (score 17):

In Task Scheduler, create a task to run the application under the NETWORK SERVICE user.
You can then run the task from the command line using

```
schtasks /run /TN "taskname"
```

Where *taskname* is the name of your task.

Comment: how to create this task using nt authority\localservice?

Comment: Is possible to run mmc.exe as localservice?

Answer (score 6):

You can only impersonate as service account from a Windows service typically, like [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20081104064404/http://geek.hubkey.com/2008/02/impersonating-built-in-service-account.html) mentions:

> The trick is to run your code as Local System and from there you can impersonate the service accounts by using the appropriate username with no password. One way to run your code as the Local System account is to create a command line shell by using the technique shown below (taken from this [orginal post](https://web.archive.org/web/20081104064404/http://blogs.msdn.com/adioltean/articles/271063.aspx)), and execute your assembly from there. Calling `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` in your code allows you to debug.
>
> To create a command-line shell that runs under the local system account, open a new command line window and enter:
>
> ```
> c:\sc create testsvc binpath= "cmd /K start" type= own type= interact
> ```
>
> followed by:
>
> ```
> c:\sc start testsvc
> ```
>
> A new command window should have opened up. In that window run your application.exe - you'll see that you're now running as the built-in System user account. After you've finished testing, you can delete the test service you created by entering:
>
> ```
> c:\sc delete testsvc
> ```

If you try to do that in your own user context, then such attempts should fail.

Answer (score 5):

I have tested

```
PsExec -i -s cmd.exe
```

and

```
PsExec -i -u "nt authority\network service" cmd.exe
```

on PsExec64-v2.2, for win10-home-x64-10.0.14393 and win10-pro-x64-10.0.15063 to use normal console it's failed, use elevated console it works fine

Comment: This approached can be confirmed using the "whoami" command, which works both in cmd.exe and Powershell.exe.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but it is the top result for this problem and I wanted to be able to run a command using PowerShell without having to install any additional tools on our Windows Server. I came up with the following PowerShell script that creates a scheduled task, runs it, and then deletes it. It is also written to allow you to run the command under different user accounts.

```
function InstallDotNetCoreGlobalTool($PackageId, $Action = "install", $User = "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE", $Password = "")
{
    $TaskName = "AzureDotNetCoreGlobalToolConfiguration"
    $Command = "dotnet.exe"
    $Arguments = "tool $Action -g " + $PackageId
    $TaskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $Command -Argument $Arguments

    Write-Host "Setting up scheduled task to run" $Command $Arguments

    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -User $User -Action $TaskAction
    Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName

    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Waiting on scheduled task to complete."

    while ((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName).State  -ne 'Ready') 
    {
      # keep waiting
    }

    Write-Host ""

    If((Get-ScheduledTask $TaskName | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo).LastTaskResult -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host $PackageId $Action "completed successfully"
    }
    else
    {
        If ($Action -eq "install")
        {
            Write-Host $PackageId "failed to $Action. Ensure the proper dependencies have been installed or that it isn't already installed."
        }
        Else {
            Write-Host $PackageId "failed to $Action. It may not currently be installed."
        }        
    }

    Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -Confirm:$false
}

InstallDotNetCoreGlobalTool "Amazon.Lambda.Tools" "uninstall"
```