# Access Certificate Store from LocalService Account

Tags: certificate, windows-server-2008-r2, certificate-store

Is there any way to access and view the certificate store of the LocalService account?

I would like to add and delete certificates. (Using Windows Server 2008 R2)

I tried:

```
runas /user:"NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" mmc.exe
```

Also:

```
schtasks /create /sc once /st 09:36 /f /tr mmc.exe /tn taskname /ru LOCALSERVICE
schtasks /run /TN "taskname"
```

Without luck :(

Answer (score 5):

Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911310/how-do-i-runas-network-service) suggested using PsExec for running commands with a service account.

Run psexec as administrator:

```
psexec -i -u "nt authority\local service" cmd.exe
```

In the new command window run:

```
certmgr.msc
```

I do not know if this will solve you problem, it is just a suggestion...

Comment: psexec needs to be installed. Is there any way to do without installing third-party programs?

Comment: I do not know any other than the ones you mentioned

Comment: For anyone coming across this after 2013, psexec is a Microsoft tool and can be downloaded from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/